# How to find the first and last occurrences of a specific character inside a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to find the first and the last occurrences of a specific character inside a string. As an example, consider a string named "2010-####-3434", and suppose the character to be searched for is "#". The first occurrence of hash inside the string is at 6-th position, and the last occurrence is at 9-th position.

Comment: See also: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Strposrev

Comment: [See my answer for how to do this with a 9.5+](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42712925/124486)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how to do that, but the regular expression functions like `regexp_matches`, `regexp_replace`, and `regexp_split_to_array` may be an alternative route to solving your problem.

Comment: I assume it is kind of a template which must be filled in. in that case regexp_replace("#+",'ABCD') will replace the #### with ABCD. The '+' sign signifies to match 1 or more of the character before it. It is all explained in detail here : http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: split_part(string, delimiter, occurrence) might help

Answer (score 38):

Well...

```
Select position('#' in '2010-####-3434');
```

will give you the first.
If you want the last, just run that again with the reverse of your string.  A pl/pgsql string reverse can be found [here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2005-02/msg00333.php).

```
Select length('2010-####-3434') - position('#' in reverse_string('2010-####-3434')) + 1;
```

Comment: as a function
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_position(text, char)
           RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
            Select length($1) - position($2 in reverse($1)) + 1;
           $$;`

Comment: I slightly amended @MFARID's function to do this with a longer substring:  `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_position(text, text) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL AS $$ Select length($1) - position(reverse($2) in reverse($1)) - length($2); $$;` - so `last_position('Thomas omas omas', 'oma')` gives 11

Comment: it's not reverse_string, it's reverse()

Answer (score 7):

My example:

```
reverse(substr(reverse(newvalue),0,strpos(reverse(newvalue),',')))
```

1. Reverse all string
2. Substring string
3. Reverse result

Comment: This is quite a neat "one-liner", and it does something - just not what the OP asked for!  It finds the last position of a comma in a string, and then returns the original string after that point.  Kudos to putting this together, but it would be so much more useful to others (including me!) if it said what it actually does.

Answer (score 5):

In the case where `char = '.'`, an escape is needed. So the function can be written:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_post(text,char) 
RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL AS $$  
select length($1)- length(regexp_replace($1, E'.*\\' || $2,''));  
$$;
```

Answer (score 4):

## 9.5+ with `array_positions`

Using basic [PostgreSQL array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) we call `string_to_array()`, and then feed that to `array_positions()` like this `array_positions(string_to_array(str,null), c)`

```
SELECT
  arrpos[array_lower(arrpos,1)] AS first,
  arrpos[array_upper(arrpos,1)] AS last
FROM ( VALUES
  ('2010-####-3434', '#')
) AS t(str,c)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL array_positions(string_to_array(str,null), c)
  AS arrpos;
```

Answer (score 3):

This pure SQL function will provide the last position of a char inside the string, counting from 1. It returns 0 if not found ... But (big disclaimer) it breaks if the character is some regex metacharacter ( `.$^()[]*+` )

```
CREATE FUNCTION last_post(text,char) RETURNS integer AS $$ 
     select length($1)- length(regexp_replace($1, '.*' || $2,''));
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

test=# select last_post('hi#-#-#byte','#');
 last_post
-----------
         7

test=# select last_post('hi#-#-#byte','a');
 last_post
-----------
         0
```

A more robust solution would involve pl/pgSQL, as rfusca's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to count last position is to slit string to array by delimeter equals to needed character and then substract length of characters 
for the last element from the length of whole string

```
CREATE FUNCTION last_pos(char, text) RETURNS INTEGER AS
$$
select length($2) - length(a.arr[array_length(a.arr,1)]) 
from (select string_to_array($2, $1) as arr) as a
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

For the first position it is easier to use

```
select position('#' in '2010-####-3434');
```