# splitting strings in postgres

Tags: postgresql, string

I have a string with some spaces in it, and would like to split on the **last** space, and return the part of the string before that space.  Does Postgres support this?  I have not been able to solve this with the usual split_part-type functions.
Example : "fort worth tx" -> "fort worth"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does not split the source string, but does what you want:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('fort worth tx', '\\s\\S+$', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a plpgsql function to accomplish this.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965655/how-to-find-the-first-and-last-occurrences-of-a-specific-character-inside-a-strin) for function to find last occurrence of string.