# Replacing First and Last JSON Characters in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a long JSON object and I want to replace the first and last brackets ([ and ]).  When I convert the JSON to varchar or text it gets truncated.  How can prevent it from being truncated and/or replace these characters?

TIA

Comment: Found this which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965655/how-to-find-the-first-and-last-occurrences-of-a-specific-character-inside-a-stri

Comment: These functions require a string.  If I convert the json it gets trunctaed.

Comment: Can you please provide the structure of this JSON? How long is it?

Comment: I tried a JSON with >400k chars. Converting to text is no problem so far.